# Force IMAP folder to completly resync in iOS Mail

Tags: email, imap, ios, mobile-mail

[iPhone 6, iOS 10.0.2]

I recently added a new IMAP email account (hosted at Rackspace, FWIW) to my phone using the standard Add Email Account settings. Everything seemed to go well... except when I now access my Sent folder (located on the server), there are obvious emails missing from the list displayed in Mail. If I search for the "missing" emails, they can be found, but they still don't show up in the list for email in Sent.  There are 978 emails in the folder, but maybe 150 shown on the iPhone?  And the list goes all the way to the first date of emails in the folder, it is just that somehow, ~150 arbitrary emails of the 978 were chosen to be listed.  Trying to refresh the folder does not help.  Any suggestions on how to see all the emails in the folder?

Comment: So it's 150 arbitrary (random from throughout the folder) and not just the first 150 in the folder (starting with oldest)? I know in Gmail you can specify how much is visible via IMAP, so there might be a setting somewhere on the server side that is affecting this.

Comment: @tubedogg correct it is emails randomly throughout the folder, not the oldest/newest 150. I will double-check with RS.

Comment: Update: I am seeing this problem in other "large" (> ~250?) email folders as well.

Comment: Update 2: Looks like the emails... eventually appeared? Weird. Anyway, problem no longer exists.